# Do I need conduit inside the wall when transitioning EMT from outdoor to inside garage?

Tags: electrical, emt

When bringing EMT run from outside to inside (THHN wires), do the wires just hang in the air from one conduit body (sitting outside) to the other conduit body (sitting inside the garage)? Or do I need to insert a 4" piece of conduit inside the wall (existing stucco/drywalled wall)?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Conduit must be complete. THHN wires hanging in wall space are not an acceptable wiring method. In this case, it's usually easier to use IMC or RMC for the nipple in the wall, as you can't get in there to tighten fasteners on EMT fittings, and assembled EMT+fittings takes a bigger hole than RMC or IMC.

That does mean getting or making a threaded nipple of the correct length.

Comment: Thanks... If I run Romex in the conduit, could I run the romex thru the wall without nipple the suggested nipple? Based on various posts I think my application would qualify for running romex in conduit

Comment: I guess it depends whether your exterior conduit is considered a wet location, which I think it is.  If you want to transition from THHN outside, you should replace the conduit body with a junction box (suitable size for the size and number of splices you'll do).  Then you can transition in the JB from THHN to NM and keep the NM inside the house.

Comment: All external conduit is defined as a wet location, so no NM/B is allowed. It's also awful to pull in conduit. And a picky inspector might not permit it in the outside junction box, either.

Comment: you guys are correct... outdoor is wet. I may go with the Junction box suggestion. Thanks